# Make children divs equal in height of tallest child

Tags: css

I have two child  elements inside of a parent container  as shown:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="item">
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p class="equal-height">Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p class="equal-height">Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p class="equal-height">Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p>Sup?</p>
    <p class="equal-height">Wish that other guys was the same height as me</p>
</div>
```

I want that the text/image content in the class "equal-height" should have the same height of the largest text in either of the columns in the class "equal-height". I'm unable to figure out.

Comment: Are you using some CSS Framework?

Comment: You can use the `align-items: stretch` property of css `flexbox`

Comment: It's not possible with pure css. You can set `.equal-height{ height: 100px}` for example, but sa I understand you need to have it dunamic. So it's possible only with js

Comment: please search before you post,